# How to use Spring Security from console

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have api application. And i use Spring Security.

When i run app, i can visit /login. I got cookies. And entered the system. After I can make requests to api.

But how to do it from console?

For example:

```
curl -u admin:123 http://localhost:8080/api/musicList
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to manage the cookies when invoking a web page from console (like wget)?

Have a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

Comment: Receiving data in two stages.
1) Sending login and password, saving cookies.
2) Getting the liver, request endpoint.
How to do this in one query?
For example I want to get post /api/musiclist/. And attach a name and password to the request. As a result, get the data.

Comment: I can't help without more details... So, when you do it using the browser, you are asked for a login? You insert your credentials, and then you can access, right? (pls try in a incognito mode if you have doubt)